# How to get selected value from DropdownlistFor ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, viewmodel

I have a model entity

> Country and Agency

with association 1 - *

for creates a Agency

1-I create a AgencyModelView from AgencyModel with two properties

```
 IEnumerable <SelectListItem> Country
 Int32 IDCountry
```

2 - I fill Country in AgencyControler with `CountryRepositery.All Country ()`

3 - I send AgencyModelView to View (Create.cshtml)

```
 @ Html.DropDownListFor (model => model.IDCountry, Model. Country)
```

It works very well Dropdownliste displays all the selctlistItem but when I submit the form to the AgencyControler

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create (AgencyModelView _AgencyModelView)
```

I do not recover anything on the Country property to determine the user's choice

```
 _ AgencyModelView. Country = null
```

problems?????

Answer (score 0):

That's weird that you get the actual dropdown correctly, since according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor) it should be the other way around. The first parameter should be `model=>model.Country` and the second should be `Model.IDCountry`.

Comment: thank you but on the footer of your link you can read
Usage Note
In Visual Basic and C#, you can call this method as an instance method on any object of type HtmlHelper(Of TModel). When you use instance method syntax to call this method, omit the first parameter. 
 I tried to reverse but it does not compile

Answer (score 0):

according to your code if you want to get the user choice then you should check the `_AgencyModelView.IDCountry`